# Draw a line in Azure Maps using Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-maps

I'm trying to make the example to draw a line in Azure Maps, showed in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/tree/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Custom%20Modules/Custom%20Drawing%20Tools, but I have no idea how to make it work, can anyone tell me how to import the LineDrawingTool.js ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include those files in your project and reference it. Once project is created, place .js files in src folder and in the html file reference with the file name.

[image]